# Removing bytes from even adresses in C

Tags: c, file

I have to remove from a file the bytes found at even addresses in C. I have opened the file for rw, I have found its length and put the content in a buffer. How can I loop every byte? I have tried this, to see what do I have in buffer:

```
for(i=0;i<len;i=i+2)
    printf("%d",buffer[i])
```

But in the buffer are saved the ASCII codes of the characters. Does it have any impact on my future line codes? And I have to write the desired output in another file, or I can just erase the initial content of the file and write in the file the modified buffer?

Comment: You can try to replace the bytes in the even address with the bytes in the odd bytes. `for (i=2;i<len;i=i+2) { buffer[i-1]=buffer[i]; }`.

Comment: What is not working? What is your input? What is your actual output? What is your expected output? Show your code instead of describing it. Does your program compile?

Comment: You should explain what "is not working"... a semi-colon is missing at the end of `printf`, maybe that is why ...

Comment: That is a strange task. Are you trying to convert a file saved with the UTF-16 encoding of Unicode to some other encoding or character set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you intend to write the buffer back to the file, then simply overwrite the buffer in this manner:

```c
int front = 0;
int back = 0;
while (front < len) {
    buffer[back] = buffer[front];
    back++;
    front += 2;
}
int newLen = back;
// Write the buffer to disk using the the new length (newLen)
```